# Lime js game works fine in iPad but jerky in Firefox

Tags: html, limejs

I have a HTML5 game which has been written in Lime JS, it works fine and smooth on the iPad but does not work smooth on Firefox (running on a pc which I assume is more powerful than an iPad and has a better graphics card), every couple of seconds the animation jumps or is choppy.

The game runs at 60FPS on the pc and around 30FPS on the iPad.

There is too much code to paste but in general has anyone come across this problem or are there any good ways to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a minimal working example?  That is reduce the code to something smaller that yields the same problem?

Comment: Hi dustin, http://bit.ly/137O64P

Comment: I am using Firefox on my laptop and everything was fine when I viewed the animation.

Comment: keep watching it :D, as the objects move down there is an occasional blip, its not consistent and appears to be random

Comment: Disable all extensions and try again.

Comment: this is a clean firefox install on multiple machines of varying hardware and OS, no extensions installed (including firebug).